# Why has the preposition been moved to the end of the sentence?

Tags: grammaticality

> The school is surrounded by big trees and grassy fields that the children use to play football on

I've come across it in the school Olympiad, so I don't think it was wrong.

In this example, the sentence wouldn't be correct If the preposition was in the beginning as i think, so it is a bit confusing for me.

Comment: The idea that a sentence cannot end with a preposition is wrong, and has been very widely discussed on this site and elsewhere.

Comment: It's grammatical where it is, and it's there because the author wanted to put it there.

Comment: I would like to know: Do you feel the word _on_ is out-of-place because it is unneeded? Or because you've been told a widely-debunked myth – namely, that prepositions don't belong at the end of sentences?

Comment: @J.R. i don't think it is out-of-place, i just wanted to know why it is there,why it could be put in the end but not in the beginning, what rule it obeys etc. And i mixed the words up, sorry. I wanted to type "begging", not "end".

Comment: @MichaelHarvey i mixed the words up., I typed "end" instead of "beggining" for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this sentence:

> The children play football ***on** the field*.

The prepositional phrase *on the field* identifies where the children play football.

In the longer sentence you cite:

> The school is surrounded by big trees and grassy fields *that the children use to play football on*.

the clause *that the children use to play football on* is providing additional information about the grassy fields.

We could rewrite that sentence to look like one of these:

> - The school is surrounded by big trees and grassy fields *where the children play football*.
> - The school is surrounded by big trees and grassy fields *that the children use for football.*
> - The school is surrounded by big trees and grassy fields *that the children play football on.*

The meaning would be pretty much the same for all of those.

In the original, the *on* is merely helping the reader identify something that happens on the grassy fields around the school (in this case, the children's football games).

If the situation were different, we might construct a very similar sentence using a different proposition:

> The school is surrounded by big trees and fertile fields *that the gardeners use to grow  tomatoes in.*

That sentence could be restructured just like the original was:

> The school is surrounded by big trees and fertile fields *where the gardeners grow tomatoes*.

Comment: Thank you, but what if the preposition is put in the beginning, is it possible? I mean, it's about "defining and non-defining clauses" if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @So_sour The sentence would end '...on which the children play football', '...in which the gardeners grow tomatoes'.

Comment: @So_sour - I'm having trouble understanding your question, because I'm not sure where "the beginning" is. (Beginning of the sentence? Beginning of a prepositional phrase?) But Simon may have answered your question: _The school is surrounded by grassy fields **on which** the children play football._ You need the _which_, but we can also restructure the sentence: _The children play football on the grassy fields which surround the school._

Comment: @J.R. the question is why can't I form the same sentence with "on which" without leaving out "use to". I mean, it wouldn't sound good for me if it were "on which children use to play football". Talking about "the beginning" i mean the beginning of the prepositional phrase.

Comment: @So_sour - Rarely is there only one way to express a thought in English. This sentence also works: _The school is surrounded by big trees and grassy fields on which the children play football._ Just because the author wrote it differently doesn't make one way correct and the other way wrong.